# Why only elements generated from loop get the "key" attribute?

Tags: reactjs

According [Recursing-on-children](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

> When children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the
>   original tree with children in the subsequent tree.

And using the key will help the optimization phase.

Why do we only need to assign the "key" attribute to elements in a loop though? Aren't other elements also the children of a parent node (elements that aren't generated from loop)? Why don't we assign the key attribute to them as well? Can the diff algorithm in React differentiate the two?